# Invalid value for key 'integrated security'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need a help. I got this:

```
SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0; Integrated Security=SSPI" + "AttachDbFilename=E:\\user\\program\\Database1.mdf");
```

I tried to set Integrated Security to **True** or even **False**. None of them works. Help!

Comment: Maybe you need some space after `SSPI` part like `SSPI " + "AttachDbFilename`?

Comment: Have you tried to append a `;` after SSPI?

Comment: Question closed, but it actually helped me solve my problem. In a big list of connection strings (web.config) there was one with a comma instead of a semicolon after SSPI, something which is hard to notice at a glance. But reading this made me take a second look and I noticed it.

Comment: in my case I have a wrong space in my connection string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clearly, you are missing a semi-colon after SSPI, so the argument is being read as `SSPIAttachDbFilename=E:\\user\\program\\Database1.mdf` which is not a valid value for Integrated Security.

This should work.

```
var sc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0; Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
                               + "AttachDbFilename=E:\\user\\program\\Database1.mdf")
```